# Powershell - Output Large Group to ImportExcel

Tags: powershell

My goal to see which members of a specific OU also have membership in a higher level AD group.  The higher level AD group has greater than 7500 members.  The following script I adopted from other sources.  It’s quick and gives me my expected results, it runs in a just a few seconds.

Here’s my problem if I pipe the results to a .txt file they are fine.  If I pipe them to the popular ImportExcel module it gives me an entry for every member in the AD group.  The ones not in the targeted OU have blanks, the others are populated.  So what I am left with is a spreadsheet of greater then 7500 rows with my data scattered throughout. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$OUpath = 'OU=ourOU,OU=Users,OU=OurDept,DC=ourdc'
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroup "MyGroup" -Properties Member |
    Select-Object -Expand Member


$out = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Property Name, DisplayName, CanonicalName | ForEach-Object {
    $n = [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        CanonicalName = $_.CanonicalName
        IsInGroup = $false
    }

    if ($GroupMembers -contains "OU=ourOU") {
        $n.IsInGroup = $true
    }
    $n
}

$out | Export-Excel
```

Comment: Your code piping to Export-Excel is wrong.  On the last line, you are expanding all of the group members and then passing all 7500 down the pipeline.  Then, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the foreach-object?  Only emit the user if it's in your hashtable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
    #Get Our Users
$OUpath = 'OUDN'
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember "GroupName" | Select-Object -Expand Name

#Get Group Members
$out = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Property Name, DisplayName | ForEach-Object {
    $n = [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        IsInGroup = $false
    }

    if ($GroupMembers -contains $_.Name) {
        $n.IsInGroup = $true
    }
    $n
}

$out

$out | Export-Excel
```

Get the Group members in an array first.  Then get all users in your OU, see if they're in the group (via the -contains operator), and conditionally output their membership association as yous see fit.

By assigning the output of the loop to $out, you can check the results in memory before exporting to Excel to verify the information is in the format you desire.

EDIT:  I had just modified the code where I thought it needed to be modified but didn't have a case where I could run it against so I was shooting from the hip.  I just created conditions where I could test what you watned to verify this code.  Modifications to make it work (see above):

- Removed -Properties from Get-ADGroupMember -- it doesn't have one
- I originally changed -Property to -Properties on Get-ADUser but apparently it works fine with either

The key here is making sure that the value of the users who are members of the targeted group used for comparison (in this case, Name) are being compared against the equivalent value on the user objects from the OU in question so the -contains operator will be matching apples to apples.

Comment: Thank you.  I see your logic there, that makes sense to me now.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: No worries.  Best of luck.

Comment: @MichaelSimmons If this answer solved your problem, accept it by clicking the checkmark icon next to it.

Comment: Sorry still struggling with this one.  In your example you used Get-AdGroupMember.  From what I can tell you can't pass a property parameter to it.  Also if you have nmore then 5000 members that will fail.  I switched to GetAdGroup.  Your logic seems to work, but I can not quite getting a match on results.  I revised code above.

Comment: @MichaelSimmons, After creating the conditions for this code to work, I've verified that the code is working as I intended.  How about for how you intended?

Comment: @thepip3r yes.  Works..thanks.  I've been at this one for days.  You may want to remove your OU info from the example.

Comment: @MichaelSimmons, GAH!  Edit fail... ty.

Answer (score 0):

@thepip3r so I had to make some modifications.  I switched to Get-AdGroup as Get-ADGroupMember caps at 5000.  When I tested your script yesterday I was using a smaller group.  To compensate for the use of Get-AdGroup I match on DistinguishedName.  I added several groups and wrapped it in a ForEach.  Three of these groups have more then 5K users.  The whole thing runs in my environment under 30 seconds.  Feel free to make suggestions.

```
#Where Excel file is to be saved
$xlSourcefile = "c:\mypath\filename.xlsx"

#The list of groups you want to check an OU's membership against
$groups = @(
    "MyGroup1"
    "MyGroup2"
    "MyGroup3"
    "MyGroup4"
    "MyGroup5" 
)


Foreach ($group in $groups) {

#The OU whoose members you want to check against the groups
$OUpath = 'OU=ourOU,OU=Users,OU=OurDept,DC=ourdc'

#Using ADGroup because of 5K membership limit on Get-ADGroupMember
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroup "$group" -Properties Member | Select-Object -Expand Member

$out = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Property Name, GivenName, Surname, DistinguishedName | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object {
    $n = [pscustomobject]@{
        DistinguishedName = $_.DistinguishedName
        Name = $_.Name
        FirstName = $_.GivenName 
        LastName = $_.Surname        
        IsInGroup = $false
    }

    if ($GroupMembers -contains $_.DistinguishedName) {
        $n.IsInGroup = $true
    }
    $n
}

    $out | Export-Excel $xlSourcefile -WorksheetName "$group" -AutoSize -AutoFilter 
}
```